# Composition of linear mappings

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space, $v,u∈V$, and let $T_1:V→V$ and $T_2:V→V$ be linear transformations such that
$T_1(v)=5v+2u, 
  T_1(u)=−2v−6u,
T_2(v)=3v−6u,   T_2(u)=5v+2u.$
Find the images of $v$ and $u$ under the composite of $T_1$ and $T_2$.

I tried computing $T_2(5v+2u)$ and  $T_2(-2v-6u)$, but this does not seem to be the answer and I don't have a clue how to proceed. Thanks!

Comment: What if the composite of $T_1$ and $T_2$. Is it $T_1\circ T_2$ or is it $T_2\circ T_1$?

Comment: They are linear transformations, just apply linearity.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos the question literally reads : $(T_2 T_1)(u)$ and the same for $v$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have\begin{align}T_2\bigl(T_1(v)\bigr)&=T_2(5v+2u)\\&=5T_2(v)+2T_2(u)\\&=5(3v-6u)+2(5v+2u)\\&=25v-26u.\end{align}The computation of $T_2\bigl(T_1(u)\bigr)$ is similar.

Comment: I see now, I had seriously misunderstood. Thanks!